# Thread Safety on interfaces. Does it make sense to use it?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

While reading [java concurrency in practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) (btw, an excellent book), I ended up with the following related questions. The first one is about **documenting** thread safety, the second is about **proving** that a class that depends on an interface is thread safe.

**Question 1.** Does it make sense to use [@ThreadSafe](https://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/concurrent/ThreadSafe.html) on interfaces? Is it a way of communicating that all the implementations must be thread safe? I am still trying to make up mind here, not sure if it is a good practice or not.

Consider the following example.

```
public interface Point {
    int getX();
}

class ImmutablePoint implements Point {
    private final int x;

    public ImmutablePoint(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

class MutablePoint implements Point {
    public int x;

    public MutablePoint(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

**Question 2.** Let's assume that you need to decide if the following class is ThreadSafe or not

```
// How can someone possibly know if this class is thread safe or not?
class IsItThreadSafe {
    private final int aRandomField;
    // the custom Point defined before
    private final Point point;

    public IsItThreadSafe(int aRandomField, Point point) {
        this.aRandomField = aRandomField;
        this.point = point;
    }

    public int add(){
        return aRandomField + point.getX();
    }
}
```

Since this class only depends on the interface Point, and we don't know anything about the implementation at this point (haha), how can you know if your class is thread safe or not?

I can imagine the follow scenario (pseydo code)

```
class ConcurrentRunner{
    public void run() {
        MutablePoint mutablePoint = new MutablePoint(42);
        IsItThreadSafe isItThreadSafe = new IsItThreadSafe(13, mutablePoint);

        // here pass isItThreadSafe and mutablePoint to multiple threads
        // each thread can modify mutablePoint and then run add()
        // different threads may get different results, the class is not behaving 
        // the same, so it should not be treated as thread safe.
    }
}
```

What do you think guys? I am sure that I am missing something fundamental here, but I don't know what!

Comment: You should post two questions if you have two questions.

Comment: I think `@ThreadSafe` is an *implementation detail* which means that it belongs on the class. Also, what if there's a way to implement the interface in a super efficient way that works perfectly in a single threaded application. (Think `StringBuffer` vs `StringBuilder.)

Comment: You can't prove that class is thread safe without understanding what it does and how it is used.  Even a thread safe class, mis-used means you don't have thread safe code.

Comment: @aioobe I think I agree with your 1st statement. Unfortunately I didn't get your 2nd.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't see how a ThreaSafe class can be misused and give you problems. If it is thread safe, it can't be misused, right?

Comment: @alexandros For example StringBuffer is thread safe, however it's almost impossible to use it a thread safe manner in a practical sense.

Comment: @alexandros Another example is `java.util.Vector`. All its methods are synchronized, so it might appear to be thread-safe, but it isn't thread-safe under iteration.

Comment: Most of the time it is an implementation detail (i.e. related to classes only), but there are situations (e.g. ConcurrentMap) when an interface is created specifically for concurrency.